# How can I find out what items a user has purchased?

Tags: posts, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm using WordPress E-Commerce ([get shopped](http://getshopped.org/)) and would like to get a list of items that a user has purchased, just a list of post IDs would be perfect. Is there any way for me to get this?

It must be stored somewhere.. has anyone attempted this before?

Answer (score 2):

Query the table wp_wpsc_purchase_logs,  it contains all information about  previous purchases.

add this to your themes functions.php:

```
/*********************************************************
Get purchased articles by user_id or for the current user
*********************************************************/
function haet_recently_bought_articles($user_id=0){
    if($user_id==0)
        $user_id=get_current_user_id();

    //only if there is an active user, otherwise we would get all purchased items from unregistered users
    if($user_id>0) {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT prodid, name, price
                FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."wpsc_cart_contents` 
                INNER JOIN `".$wpdb->prefix."wpsc_purchase_logs` ON purchaseid = ".$wpdb->prefix."wpsc_purchase_logs.id
                WHERE  user_ID = %d
                ORDER BY date DESC"
                ,$user_id);
        $items = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
        return $items;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and add the following lines to the template to show the products e.g. page-.php

```
<ul class="articles">
    <?php 
    $articles = haet_recently_bought_articles();
    foreach($articles AS $article){
        echo '<li>'.$article['name'].'</li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: An example would probably be useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
global $wpsc_cart;
```

This is the global variable , looping through this will get all the info ie products added in cart by user, just do

```
 print_r( $wpsc_cart; )
```

and you will come to know.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. I'm looking for a full list of purchases, not just what's in the cart right now.

Comment: Shopping Cart Settings in admin presentation check <?php echo wpsc_shopping_cart(); ?> ) this gives shopping cart.

Comment: Sorry, the shopping cart isn't what I'm after. I'm after a full list of all product IDs that have been purchased by the logged in user

Comment: Shopping cart is nothing but list of all product purchased by logged in user, but why do need only product ids of product purchased by logged in user?

Comment: I'm trying to find out what products a user has bought preivously.

Comment: try this http://getshopped.org/fpt-plugins/wpec-user-roles-and-purchase-history/